# HTTP Cache-Control

Tags: javascript, firefox, http-headers, cache-control, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to HTTP caching and really need some help...

1. I saw many people set the `"Cache-Control"` header when sending XHR to server.
   What is the purpose of doing that? Does request header needs caching too?
2. I've set this header for a XHR:
   `Cache-Control max-age=30, must-revalidate`, but Firefox 3.6.13 seems do not re-validate the file when I refresh(even force refresh) after 30 seconds. No access-log in server either. Is this because I haven't set expire header to the file in Apache?

   From Firebug log:

   > **Response Headers**
   >   Date Sat, 22 Jan 2011 09:59:21 GMT
   >   Last-Modified Thu, 20 Jan 2011 09:05:11 GMT
   >   Etag "3e000000023ca7-20d-49a436e5b3413"
   >
   > **Request Headers**
   >   Keep-Alive 115
   >   Connection keep-alive
   >   Content-Type application/xml
   >   Cache-Control max-age=30, must-revalidate

   The file have been modified, but Firefox does not even do conditional get. `Response Date` and `Last-Modified` not update at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the server needs to set the re-validate directive, not the client.

the source controls if and how the content should be cacehd or not cached, the clients decides whether to honor it or not.

must-revalidate just means that a head request is sent and if the etag differes, the resources is refreshed. this is a very common an dsenseful practice for big files, because the e-tag generally changes once the content changes.

for small files however it may be your desire to not have any request at all, but a shorter time out. then must-revalidate is wrong.
the server load and the time it consumes of a head request to a 7kb image is not much less than serving the complete image.

Answer (score 2):

Clients can send Cache-Control directives too.  See:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-12#section-3.2

Unfortunately, browsers won't (yet) honour them when set by XHR, but intervening proxy caches generally will.

Comment: Yes clients can send Cache-Control directives too, but according to that IETF document (and Mozilla's documentation) must-revalidate is not one of the directives that clients can set, so the answer is correct to say "the server needs to set the re-validate directive, not the client". But I agree it would be useful if they also said max-age can be set by the client. I'm not sure which browser versions do and don't honour them on the client side though; best set everything on the server. (See also Chromium issue 333804 fixed in Chrome 35: it still affects WebView components in Android 4.4 apps.)